# Please check that the PPA name or format is correct

Tags: add-apt-repository

installing ansible on ubuntu os,

on typing the command :

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:ansible/ansible
```

it is showing

```
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

how to fix this issue?

Comment: Check the PPA name is correct?

Comment: There is no issue in the ppa name. It works fine for me.  Try adding it to sources.list manually.  Is software-properties-common installed?

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
software-properties-common is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 295 not upgraded.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:ansible/ansible'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.

Comment: it is giving the same msg again and again ......

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install Ansible on Ubuntu 14.04 from the terminal without the having to run the `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ansible/ansible` command, follow these steps.

1. Open the terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update  
   sudo apt-get install software-properties-common  
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. The last command will open your sources.list file, which specifies the software sources in Ubuntu, for editing in nano text editor. Add the following lines to the end of the sources.list file:

   ```
   deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu trusty main 
   deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu trusty main
   ```

   Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes in sources.list. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.
3. Pull down Ansible PPA's signing key and add it to your system.

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7BB9C367
   ```
4. Run these commands to update the list of available software once again and install Ansible.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update  
   sudo apt-get install ansible
   ```

Alternatively you can install ansible from the default repositories in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu by running the following command.

```
sudo apt install ansible
```

Comment: I'm following the same order , at the 3rd cmd (ppa:ansible/ansible) , I'm getting the same msg this time also..

Comment: except this :sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7BB9C367         I followed the remaining steps and finally successfully installed      thanks .....